# Adding ng-model to directive

Tags: angularjs, directive, angular-ngmodel

I have the following directive to reverse geocode a lat & long into a place:

```
/* global app*/

app.directive('reverseGeocode', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            template: '<div ng-model="autoLocation"></div>',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(attrs.lat, attrs.lng);
                geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        if (results[1]) {
                            element.text(results[1].formatted_address);
                        } else {
                            element.text('Location not found');
                        }
                    } else {
                        element.text('');
                    }
                });
            },
            require: "ngModel",
            replace: true
        }
    });
```

But for some reason, it doesn't seem to retrieve the ng-model and display it:

```
<div class="form-group move-down" ng-class="{ 'has-error': place === null }">
            <label for="place">Picture taken in:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-if="!capture.geo" id="place" ng-model="place.formatted_address" ng-autocomplete options="options" required details="place" ng-click="checkPlace(place)"
            uib-tooltip="Please pick the location where you captures your photo!"
            tooltip-placement="top-right"
            tooltip-trigger="mouseenter"
            tooltip-enable="!details.formatted_address"
            tooltip-class="tooltip">

            // DIRECTIVE USED HERE
            <reverse-geocode class="form-control" ng-if="capture.geo" lat="{{capture.latitude}}" lng="{{capture.longitude}}">
            <div ng-show="place === null" class="noPlace">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i> Please fill in a valid location!
            </div>
        </div>
```

What my goal is, is to display the location below using:

```
<div ng-if="capture.geo">Place: {{autoLocation}}</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a working plunkr/fiddle

Comment: Also, where is the closing tag of `reverse-geocode` directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to drop `restrict` or at least use `E` (element) instead of `A` (attribute), since you are using the directive as element.

Second, you don't need to add or pass `ng-model`, which is a directive itself, to your directive. You can access the controller scope variable `capture` directly. If you prefer directive to have it's own, isolated scope, then you should two-way bind the controller variable to directive's scope using `=` (or `@` if you prefer passing literal strings).

If I understood correctly, below is what you are after (simplified but functionality is there).

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  lat <input type="number" ng-model="capture.lat">
  lng <input type="number" ng-model="capture.lng">
  <reverse-geocode capture="capture"></reverse-geocode>
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.capture = {
    lat: 10.0,
    lng: 20.0
  };
})
.directive('reverseGeocode', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      capture: '='
    },
    template: '<div ng-bind="autoLocation"></div>',
    link: function(scope) {
      scope.$watch('capture', function() {
        if (scope.capture.lat && scope.capture.lng) {
          scope.autoLocation = 'reverse geocode address for [' +
            scope.capture.lat + ' ' + scope.capture.lng + '] here';
        } else {
          scope.autoLocation = 'invalid coordinates';
        }
      }, true);
    },
  }; 
});
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It won't work in that way. `ng-model` only works for input type element where a user can pass some input.

You need to use two-way data communication so that you can modify a scope variable from directive to it's associated scope's variable.